# copy_to_user undefined in linux kernel version 4.12.8

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, ubuntu-16.04

In my project I am using char driver to communicate between user space and kernel space. I use the function `copy_to_user(void user *to, const void *from, unsigned long n)` to copy data from kernel space to user space buffer. We can find this function under `#include < asm/uaccess.h >` header file.
I complied the project using Linux Kernel version 4.4.0-59-generic, Ubuntu OS version 16.04 LTS and its working fine without any error and warning. I get the desired output.

I compiled the same project using Linux kernel version 4.12.8, Ubuntu OS version 16.04.2 LTS and it throws me an warning during compile time `WARNING: "copy_to_user" [/home/ldrv1/Desktop/Vijay/code/build/uts.ko] undefined!`. When I do insmod of my module I get error as follows `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module uts.ko: Unknown symbol in module`. I think that `#include <asm/uaccess.h>` header file is still supported in 4.12.8 kernel version else I would have got fatal error: no such file or directory error while compiling. I tried updating the linux kernel headers using  `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` command and I got the following response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.12.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.12.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.12.8'
```

This OS version 16.04.2 LTS has linux-headers-4.10.0-35.
How do I get rid of this warning? Suggestions and support appreciated. If more information is required please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. You should use `#include <linux/uaccess.h>` for **4.12.8**.
   Here is the [definition](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.8/source/include/linux/uaccess.h#L164).

   In **4.4** some drivers use `#include <asm/uaccess.h>` whilst the others
   use `#include <linux/uaccess.h>`.

   `#include <linux/uaccess.h>` is preferable, I think.
2. You should do `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install linux-headers-generic`.

Comment: In 4.15, it appears that you need both <linux/uaccess.h> and <asm/uaccess.h> the header file in include/linux defines copy_to_user, the one in include/asm defines raw_copy_to_user.

Answer (score 0):

The function **copy_to_user** and **copy_from_user** defined in ***asm/uaccess.h*** . I think you have some issue when you define this function. I wrote the character device driver with some example about data transfer between Kernel space and User space. View my github: [my code](https://github.com/danghai/Kernel/tree/master/character_device_driver) for reference. Please star if you feel it is helpful for you :). it has small bug in example 3. I am figuring them, but example 1 and example 2 work well

Comment: Hi Hai, I got solution for my question, i went through your example code and its good. I have given you a star. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Bronislav Elizaveti is correct. If instead of `#include <asm/uaccess.h>` we use `#include <linux/uaccess.h>`, then we won't get the warning.

If you still want to use only `#include <asm/uaccess.h>`, then you'll need to use  `_copy_to_user` instead of `copy_to_user` (with the same arguments). A simple **`_`** will do the job.